# How to access and change a variable from a different file in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, oop, user-interface, scaffolding

I am trying to access and change a variable from a differant file in flutter. 
basically, I have created a file called ```colors.dart``` where I'll save the data on the colors that will be used in flutter app.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class colors {
  static Color bgColor = Color(0xfff8f8f8);
}
```

And I wish to change its value when I press on a button
I imported the dart file in my new file and iniside the onpressed function of my button I have:

```
MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: colors.bgColor,
...

onPressed: () {
      setState(() {
    colors.bgColor = Color(0xff313131);
  });
},
```

The color inside of bgColor.dart does show up but when  I try to change it onPressed (also in an stateful widget) it does not change the scaffold color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### If scaffold and button are in the same stateful widget

First of all make sure that `backgroundColor: colors.bgColor` and `setState` both are in the same stateful widget, it should work(tested)

### If scaffold and button are in different widgets

this way is not dependent on `setState` so you can use it in both stateless and stateful widgets

1. Change type of color to `ValueNotifier<Color>`,

optional: name types using UpperCamelCase

```
class CustomColors {
  static ValueNotifier<Color> bgColor = ValueNotifier(const Color(0xfff8f8f8));
}
```

2. wrap scaffold with a `ValueListenableBuilder` and access color with `value` property

```
    MaterialApp(
      home: ValueListenableBuilder<Color>(
        valueListenable: CustomColors.bgColor,
        builder: (context, value, child) => Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: value,
```

3. to change color:

```
onPressed: () {
    CustomColors.bgColor.value = Colors.red;
}
```

Comment: type 'Color' is not a subtype of type 'ValueNotifier<Color>' of 'function result'

Comment: @HamadMoniem where are you getting this error, i have also updated answer edited the value of `backgroundColor` in 2nd step

Comment: Nevermind, I just hot restarted and the issue went away. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

You can use Shared preferences
https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences/install
Take a quick look for how to use from anywhere

Answer (score 0):

you can do using the Provider Plugin [this](https://pub.dev/packages/provider).

Answer (score 0):

```
 Color changeColor = colors.bgColor

 
MaterialApp(
  home: Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: changeColor,
...

onPressed: () {
  setState(() {
changeColor = Color(0xff313131);
});
},
```